# Do I have to go through Canadian immigration before crossing the border by walk to the US?

Tags: usa, canada, borders

I'm going from Canada to the States by walk crossing the border on the Rainbow Bridge. Do I get my passport stamped / have do immigration on the Canadian side in order to cross the bridge and get to the US border or is it only one way check in as when you go to Canada?

Answer (score 4):

In general, Canada does not have an "exit" immigration check / passport control anywhere else, so no, you will most likely only deal with US immigration when crossing into the US. (Disclaimer: I have never personally crossed the bridge by walking, but I have driven across it, though it was many years ago).

Comment: I've heard there are some new immigration rules that are being considered. I don't have the full details, but from what I've hear Canada is considering adding exit passport checks (perhaps even as early as 2015), so you should check the most recent rules.

Comment: See this for example: http://www.ctvnews.ca/politics/government-considering-exit-controls-to-track-homegrown-terrorists-blaney-1.2028258